# Displaying an XML string with formatting and syntax highlighting in an Eclipse RCP view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, rcp, xml-formatting

I am currently stuck on what I feel like should be an easy solution, but I am not really getting anywhere with this. I am new to Eclipse RCP. I am trying to implement a view in which, all it does, is display a string, which has been formatted to XML. As in, my application does what it is meant to do, and when the user clicks Save, it saves all the info as an xml. I can get this xml as one long, unformatted string. I want a pane where the user can see (only see, not edit) the XML code that is going to be saved.

The reason I want a view is because this view is a multi-instance view, dependent on the perspective it is in. And I want it to display in XML format, with syntax highlighting. It would be nice for it to look like in an editor with line numbers and such, but with good formatting I am satisfied.

Does anyone know the best (any) way to implement this? Even some 3rd party widget is perfect for me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, the Plug-In editor example does basic syntax coloring and you can use the javax.transform packages to go from a stream to a DOM and back to a (formatted) stream.

Answer (score 0):

just make your editor inherit from StructuredTextEditor (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.StructuredTextEditor)

For further details here:

- [FAQ How do I provide syntax coloring in an editor?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_syntax_coloring_in_an_editor%3F)
- [Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Editors](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_highlighting.htm)

Comment: This is only for Editors tho, right? I'm trying to maintain it in a view, as with a view I can do multiple instances of it (this is important to me). Also, I am not editing, just displaying text. I could format it using nitind's answer, but I guess syntax highlighting and coloring might be out of the question